# How to parsing JSON which has abnormal grammar in android?

Tags: java, android, json

When I tried to parse the JSON string in Android, there is `org.json.JSONException`

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"alias":"\ud56b\u
at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:525)
```

The data from server is as below.

```
["{\"alias\":\"\\ud56b\\ud50c\",\"address\":\"\\uad00\\ucca0\\ub3d9,\\ub300\\uce58\\ub3d9,\\uc2e0\\uc0ac\\ub3d9\"}","{\"alias\":\"\\uc2e0\\uc0ac\\ub3d9\",\"address\":\"\\uc2e0\\uc0ac\\ub3d9\"}","{\"alias\":\"\\uc591\\uc7ac\\ub3d9\",\"address\":\"\\uc591\\uc7ac\\ub3d9\"}","{\"alias\":\"\\ub79c\\ub364\",\"address\":\"\\ub300\\ud604\\ub3d9,\\ubc29\\ubc30\\ub3d9\"}","{\"alias\":\"\\uc0bc\\ud3c9\\ub3d9\",\"address\":\"\\uc0bc\\ud3c9\\ub3d9\"}","{\"alias\":\"\\ubd80\\uc804\\ub3d9\",\"address\":\"\\ubd80\\uc804\\ub3d9\"}"]
```

Could you please give me your advice how to parse it in Android?

Comment: rework the json in your server

Comment: @Sheychan Agree with you here. Maybe try fixing the server first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to remove the \ to read it properly.

Try something like this: `result = result.replace("\\", "");`

And if you want to get rid of the \ as well:

`result = result.replace("\\\\", "");`

Do it for your `"{` as well, it could be a problem.

where result is your previous and will be your new json.

But Sheychan is right, your server has to fix it, not your app.